# python reference to object in init creates shadow opposed to reference in memberfunction

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I am very very new to coding(no other language prior to python), this is my first big project that I am tackling and I encountered a bug, which I hope you can help me understand. I am using python 3.43

I have searched this site and the internet for an answer for this but only found a vague hint that maybe my imports could be the problem.
Reproducing the bug outside of my programfiles with a similar setup was unsuccesful, so it must be related to my faulty code structure.

This is my koreanwar class, which is supposed to have a reference to an instance of a countryclass from another module, that holds some numbers. My start event memberfunction of my koreanwar class is supposed to edit the numbers of that particular instance.

I extract the instance out of a dictionary that holds many such country instances via the get_country_by_name function.
Dictionary should not be the problem, if I attempt to work with a list and iterate over all countries to extract it, I get the same error.

The code as it is right now seems to create a shadow variable between the end of the **init** and the start of the start_event, as the memory adresses are different from self.korea in the **init** and self.korea in the start_event and any change I make doesn't show on the original object.

```
class KoreanWar(WarCard):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.korea = countries.countrymodel.get_country_by_name('South Korea')
        print('init',self.korea)


    def start_event(self):
        print('start_event',self.korea)
        self.korea.influence_west = 9

        print('self.korea.influence_west_start_event ' + str(self.korea.influence_west))
        print('self.korea.influence_west_original ' + str(countries.countrymodel.get_country_by_name('South Korea').influence_west))
```

This is the Output I get and I would expect all values to be the same:

```
init <countries.countrymodel.CountryModel object at 0x0000000002F6B6D8>
start_event <countries.countrymodel.CountryModel object at 0x0000000002F74400>
self.korea.influence_west_start_event 9
self.korea.influence_west_original 1
```

What is more obscure is that when I edit self.korea in the **init** itself after referencing it, it is editing the correct object and if I print the memory adress it is the correct one.
So something magically happens between the end of the **init** and the first line of start_event which causes the creation of a shadow copy, which is then used for the start_event.

I can fix the bug by moving the self.korea reference into the memberfunction itself like this, but I like to understand why this fixes the bug and how I have created such a mess, as outside of my specific code structure I can just do it in the init without any bugs.

```
class KoreanWar(WarCard):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def start_event(self):

        self.korea = countries.countrymodel.get_country_by_name('South Korea')    
        self.korea.influence_west = 9
```

Inheritance seem to be unrelated, I tried it without and still get the same bug.
I am strictly using imports either as:

```
xy = folder, z module
a, b, c = functions, classes, lists/dictionaries
import xy.z
import xy
from xy.z import a, b, c
```

countries is a folder where I store the countrymodel.py.
countrymodel is a countrymodel.py file where I store my CountryModel Class.

#### countrymodel.py

no relevant imports here, the class gets a .txt file from the hard drive and fills in the memberattributes

```
class CountryModel:
    def __init__(self, fileName):

        self.connected_country_object_list = []
        country_file = fileName
        file = open(country_file, 'r')
        lines = file.readlines()

        for line in lines:
            lineList = line.strip('\n').split('=')
            attrName = lineList[0]
            attrValue = lineList[1]
            if attrValue.isdigit():
                attrValue = int(attrValue)
            if attrName == "current_influence_west":
                attrName = "influence_west"
            setattr(self, attrName, attrValue)

country_dict = {}

def get_country_by_name(name):
    return country_dict[name]

def create_country_dict():
    global country_dict
    keys = []
    values = []
    for country_model in country_models:
       keys.append(country_model.name)
       values.append(country_model) 
       country_dict = dict(zip(keys, values))
```

In my initialization module I actually run over all the possible countries and instantiate them and save them to the country_models-list.

#### initialization.py

```
from countries.countrymodel import CountryModel, country_models, create_country_dict

def collect_countries():
    for file in os.listdir(paths.PATH_COUNTRIES): # iterate over all possible countryfiles
        if file.endswith(".txt"): 
            country_model = CountryModel(filename)
            country_models.append(country_model)

    create_country_dict()
```

---

Update:
Found a hint to the answer. I am sending these countryobjects(for example reference self.korea) via network between computers by copying the complete countryobject. This process seems to create a new memory address for the countryobject reference and thus if the self.korea = xxx is in the init it connects only 1 time at the start to the initial memory address of the country and doesn't update it after replacing the country object, thus points to an empty or obsolete memory address.
If the self.korea reference is outside of the init, it will connect to the correct memory address everytime after the new memory address has been written for the countryobject, as it only creates the reference afterwards and everytime it is activated.
That also explains why I couldn't reproduce the issue with a simpler version of it on a single computer, because I wouldn't change the memory addresses via my networkcode.

Comment: What is countrymodel? Can you show some of get_country_by_name? And how are you verifying that the object is being copied - please show that code and the output.

Comment: I just want to point out that you should use `super().__init__` instead of `WarCard.__init__`, it is the correct way to do in Python.

Comment: @Olivier: And before they get confused, using `super()` means they don't need to (and shouldn't) pass `self` to `__init__` explicitly.

Comment: @Olivier , I always use `SuperName.__init__`, like `WarCard.__init__` whats wrong with this..?

Comment: Thank you, I have added the necessary information

Comment: @Arief: Explicitly naming the super class makes cooperative multiple inheritance nearly impossible, and it violates [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) (your class declared its parent class(es) already, you shouldn't be repeating those names over and over, especially if, over the course of development, the precise names might change). `super()` is magic; used consistently, you can ensure that every superclass's version of a method is called once, and only once, without each superclass needing full details of the child classes that inherit from them.